# Ctrl + V insert images and POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

There is a function for uploading images to the server using a regular form. They asked to make the function Ctrl + V and load the image.
I'm trying, something does not work out.

JS:

```
document.onpaste = function(event) {
  var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
  for (index in items) {
    var item = items[index];
    if (item.kind === 'file') {
      var blob = item.getAsFile();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        document.getElementById('file-upload').files[0] = event.target.result;
        document.getElementById('up-img').submit();
        //alert(event.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
  }
}
```

Form code:

```
<form action="/upload-img.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="up-img">
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</label>
<input name="steamidpost" type="hidden" value="123">
<input name="img" accept="image/*" type="file" id="file-upload" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

And php code /upload-img.php

```
<?php
    include 'conn.php'; 
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['steamidpost'])) { 
        $id = $_POST['steamidpost'];
        $img = $_FILES['img'];
        if(isset($img['name'])) {
            $filename = $img['tmp_name'];
            $client_id = "MY SECRET ID";
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
            $pvars = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
            $timeout = 30;
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID '.$client_id));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $pms = json_decode($out, true);
            $url = $pms['data']['link'];
            if(isset($url)){
                //add to mysql code
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        exit;
    }
?>
```

When using `Ctrl + V`, the code is triggered (for the test done by Alert) but the image does not load, only the page is updated. What's wrong?

Errors:

```
[Mon Oct 01 21:28:01 2018] [warn] [client #] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in ...
[Mon Oct 01 21:28:01 2018] [warn] [client #] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /upload-img.php ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Works:

```
    function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        var byteArrays = [];

        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

      var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
      return blob;


    function reloadPage(){
       window.location.reload();
    }

    function appendFileAndSubmit(getf){
        var form = document.getElementById("up-img");

        var ImageURL = getf;
        var block = ImageURL.split(";");
        var contentType = block[0].split(":")[1];
        var realData = block[1].split(",")[1];
        var blob = b64toBlob(realData, contentType);
        var fd = new FormData(form);
        fd.append("img", blob);

        $.ajax({
            url:"/upload-img.php",
            data: fd,
            type:"POST",
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            cache:false,
            dataType:"json",
            error:function(err){
                //
            },
            success:function(data){
                //
            },
            complete:function(){
                reloadPage();
            }
        });
    }

    document.onpaste = function(event){
        var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
        for (index in items) {
            var item = items[index];
            if (item.kind === 'file') {
                var blob = item.getAsFile();
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    appendFileAndSubmit(event.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            }
        }
    }
```